# IDs associated with predicted probabilities from randomForest package in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm running a random forest model using the `randomForest` package in R. I remove the ID column when training the model. I get a table of probabilities from the `predict()` function but no ID information, so no way to link back to the IDs. Is it fair to assume that they are in order of the test data set? Anyway to keep the ID column without including it in the prediction data?

Comment: Hi @wisamb! You may want to read the SO Help Center page ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post accordingly (particularly the "Help others reproduce the problem" section). As written, this question doesn't follow SO guidelines and will likely attract negative feedback (and likely be closed due to lack of details). Good luck!